# How can I rotate x axis labels so they are diagonal and not horizontal on Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly-python

I am making a bar graph on plotly but the x axis labels are converted into vertical orientation by default. I would be interested in rotating them for increased readability.

```
import requests

from plotly.graph_objs import Bar
from plotly import offline

#Make an API call and  store the response
url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars'
headers = {'Accept':'application/vnd.github.v3+json'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(f"Status code:  {r.status_code}")

#Process results
response_dict = r.json()
repo_dicts = response_dict['items']

repo_names, stars = [], []
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
    repo_names.append(repo_dict['name'])
    stars.append(repo_dict['stargazers_count'])

#Make visualization
data = [{
    'type':'bar',
    'x':repo_names,
    'y':stars,
    'marker':{
        'color':'rgb(60,100,150)',
        'line':{'width':1.5, 'color':'rgb(25,25,25)'}
    }
}]
my_layout = {
    'title': 'Most-Starred Python Projects on github',
    'titlefont':{'size':24},
    'xaxis': {
        'title':'Repository',
        'titlefont':{'size':24},
        'tickfont':{'size':14}
    },
    'yaxis': {
        'title':'Stars',
        'titlefont':{'size':24},
        'tickfont':{'size':14}
    }
}

fig = {'data':data, 'layout':my_layout}
offline.plot(fig, filename='python_repos.html')
```

My code makes this:

[image: Graph that I created]

But the vertical names on the x-axis. I would like to make horizontal.

I tried doing:

```
fig = {'data':data, 'layout':my_layout}
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=45)
offline.plot(fig, filename='python_repos.html')
```

But I get an error that says:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'update_xaxes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up a graph object and pass its contents, the data and layout, in dictionary form to fig. Once this is done, the x-axis labels can be set.

```
my_fig = dict({'data':data, 'layout':my_layout})

fig = go.Figure(my_fig)
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=45)
fig.show()

offline.plot(fig, filename='python_repos.html')
```

[image]